# Azure Function 2.0 Does not deliver exceptions to App Insights

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Azure Function 2.0 Does not deliver exceptions to App Insights following this [guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hmahrt/2017/02/17/richer-exception-details-in-application-insights-custom-exceptions/) and several others

I've written the following method to report exceptions to app insights:

```
public void PublishOperationResult(Exception ex, string CustomMessage, Guid invocationId)
{
     var _client = new TelemetryClient
     {
         InstrumentationKey = "my-key"
     };

     _client.Context.Operation.Id = invocationId.ToString();
     _client.Context.Operation.Name = "SnapshottingViewsException";

     var exception = new ExceptionTelemetry(ex);

     var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
     {
         {"CustomMessage", CustomMessage}
     };

     foreach (var property in properties)
     {
         exception.Properties.Add(property);
     }

     _client.TrackException(exception);
}
```

When calling the method I can see the exception being logged in the Visual Studio debug output but nothing appears in App Insights, both locally and on an azure consumption plan.

Debug message:

```
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.653f95d8909341b5a971eaa88c40606b.Exception","time": ...
```

If I disable this functionality and merely throw the exception everything works as expected.

Versions:

```
Microsoft.NetCoreApp 2.1.0
Microsoft.SDK.Functions 1.0.29
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.7.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, sort of.

The exception in question that I was testing with came from an SQL client. When thrown up this is seen as an exception by AppInsights but when reported by the TelemetryClient its seen as a Dependency Error with a different message/title which I wasn't looking for. And thus a little more difficult to spot.